# Using an environ environment with \newenvironment

Tags: environments, nesting

I want to use an environment defined with `NewEnviron` from [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) in another environment definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{inner}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1:} \BODY
}

\newenvironment{out}{%
  \begin{inner}{Using outer}%
}{%
  \end{inner}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{inner}{Using inner}
    Lorem ipsum\ldots
  \end{inner}

  \begin{out}
    Lorem ipsum\ldots
  \end{out}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF looks as desired:

[image]

But the log shows some erros:

```
./test.tex:22: LaTeX Error: \begin{inner} on input line 20 ended by \end{out}.
 ...                                              
l.22 \end{out}

./test.tex:23: LaTeX Error: \begin{out} on input line 20 ended by \end{document
}.
 ...                                                  
l.23 \end{document}

...
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 20 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
```

If I define `out` using `NewEnviron`, that is

```
\NewEnviron{out}{%
  \begin{inner}{Using outer}%
    \BODY
  \end{inner}%
}
```

then `pdflatex` does not terminate.

Apparently, something is mixed up (presented to the parser in the wrong order). What is going wrong?

Comment: @Raphael From the examples it's hard to understand why you want `environ` in the first place. But nesting two `\NewEnviron` defined (pseudo)environments will lead to assign to `\BODY` something that contains `\BODY`: an infinite loop is waiting for you.

Comment: @egreg In dependence of some value, I want to drop the content of an environment. Using `xifthen`, I did not see a (LaTeX) way to do it without `NewEnviron`, and it works beautifully with. Ah, right, `\BODY` prevents nesting; I think I encountered that one before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Environments within environments causing errors can be circumvented using the command-form of the environment. So, try

```
\newenvironment{out}
  {% \begin{out}
    \inner{Using outer}%
  }{% \end{out}
    \endinner%
  }
```

As mentioned in comment by egreg, nesting `\NewEnviron`s would lead to a circular reference to `\BODY` - the captured environment contents macro.

Comment: Defining `out` using `NewEnviron` and `\inner`/`\endinner` does not work, so you are skrewed if you need `NewEnviron` for the outer environment?

Comment: While you don't explicitly state this, this answer may be interpreted as it is ok to use `\inner` and `\endinner` for environments created by `\NewEnviron`. This contradicts your answer for [“Runaway argument?” error with \NewEnviron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218591/4301) which states "_`\NewEnviron{myenv} `creates a macro `\myenv` which designates the start of the environment, and this macro is on the lookout for exactly `\end{myenv}`... nothing else_". Or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: @PeterGrill: I don't infer that nor should it be interpreted that way.

Comment: @Werner: Ok. Can you edit the answer to explicitly state that. Or, do you think having these comments is adequate? I am currently have an issue with nested `\NewEnviron` and came across this answer before the other one and that is how I interpreted it.  Spent sometime trying to get the macro version of a `\NewEnviron` working, before coming across the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

The nesting problem is due to the fact that every (pseudo)environment defined with `\NewEnviron` uses `\BODY` for storing the contents.

Actually the control sequence name can be modified, but not after an environment has started. One might use directly `\collect@body` or `\Collect@Body`, but this would be very cumbersome.

My suggestion is to define *two* versions of the same environment:

```
\newenvironment{innerx}[1]
 {\textbf{#1:}}
 {}

\NewEnviron{inner}[1]{%
  \innerx{#1} \BODY
}

\newenvironment{outx}
  {\innerx{Using outer}}
  {\endinnerx}

\NewEnviron{out}{\outx~\BODY\endoutx}
```

Of course, in the present example the `outx` environment is not necessary and

```
\NewEnviron{out}{\innerx{Using outer} \BODY\endinnerx}
```

would suffice.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\newenvironment{innerx}[1]
 {\textbf{#1:}}
 {}

\NewEnviron{inner}[1]{%
  \innerx{#1} \BODY
}

\newenvironment{outx}
  {\innerx{Using outer}}
  {\endinnerx}

\NewEnviron{out}{\outx~\BODY\endoutx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{inner}{Using inner}
    Lorem ipsum\ldots
  \end{inner}

  \begin{out}
    Lorem ipsum\ldots
  \end{out}
\end{document}
```

## Update

With `environ` version 0.3, dated 2014/05/04, it's easier to have nested environments defined with `\NewEnviron`. When the

```
\environbodyname<control sequence>
```

command is found, every `\NewEnviron` from that point on should be defined using `<control sequence>` instead of `\BODY`. Here's an example based on the previous code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{out}{%
  \begin{inner}{Using outer}%
    \BODY
  \end{inner}%
}

\environbodyname\innerBODY
\NewEnviron{inner}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1:} \innerBODY
}

\begin{document}

\begin{inner}{Using inner}
Lorem ipsum\ldots
\end{inner}

\begin{out}
Lorem ipsum\ldots
\end{out}

\end{document}
```

[image]