# Nested Environ's give "! Argument of ... has an extra }" error

Tags: equations, environments, amsmath, nesting

I tried using two Environ's in a nested fashion, but I get the

```
! Argument of \marray has an extra }
```

error. Any idea why this happens?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}

\NewEnviron{meqmultinum}[1]{
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\BODY
\end{split}\label{eq:#1}\end{equation}
}

\NewEnviron{marray}[2]{
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#2}
\begin{array}{#1}
\BODY
\end{array}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{meqmultinum}{test}
a&=\begin{marray}{l l}{1.2}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \kappa
\end{marray}\\
b&=\begin{array}{l l}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \kappa
\end{array}
\end{meqmultinum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You would avoid the problem (and the code would be a lot more efficient if you use `\newenvironment{marray}[2]{\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#2}\begin{array}{#1}}{\end{array}` you only need the `\BODY` construct in cases where you need to pass the enviornment body as a comamnd argument.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78692/13034) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Environment `split` inside `meqmultinum` provides an alignment. That means that the contents of the environment is processed cell by cell:

Cell 1:  `a`
Cell 2: `=\begin{marray}{l l}{1.2} \alpha`

The rest `& \beta \\ \gamma & \kappa \end{marray}` does not belong to cell 2.
Thus the code of `\begin{marray}` complains, because it cannot find `\end` of `\end{marray}`.

This can be fixed by adding curly braces around `\begin{marray}...\end{marray}`:

```
\begin{meqmultinum}{test}
  a&={\begin{marray}{l l}{1.2}
    \alpha & \beta\\
    \gamma & \kappa
  \end{marray}}\\
  ...
\end{meqmultinum}
```

Why does it work with `array` instead of `marray`? Environment `array` does not need to see at the beginning `\end{array}`, instead it sets up a tabular and the contents of `array` with its `&` is processed in this inner tabular.

### Other definition of `marray`

Another way to fix this issue is given by David Carlisle in his comment. There is no need for the special environment processing of package `environ` for `array`:

```
\newenvironment*{marray}[2]{%
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#2}%
  \begin{array}{#1}%
}{‌%
  ​\end{array}%
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `\NewEnviron` for these environments; in this case `split` can give problems, but `aligned` can be used instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{meqmultinum}[1]
  {\equation\label{eq:#1}\aligned}
  {\endaligned\endequation}

\newenvironment{marray}[2]
  {\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#2}\array{#1}}
  {\endarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{meqmultinum}{test}
a&=\begin{marray}{l l}{1.2}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \kappa
\end{marray}\\
b&=\begin{array}{l l}
\alpha & \beta\\
\gamma & \kappa
\end{array}
\end{meqmultinum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the \something...\endsomething notation instead of \begin{something}...\end{something}. Do you have a reference that explains this?

Comment: @Wox The usage of `\foo` and `\endfoo` instead of `\begin{foo}` and `\end{foo}` is sometimes handier; it has pros and cons: it doesn't form a group and doesn't set the environment's name (so error messages may be more helpful), but for some environments, notably `lrbox` it *mustn't* be used.