# Problems using hooks

Tags: environments, hooks

I am trying to duplicate a document using hooks at the beginning and the end. Here is a minimal example of my problem :

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{forloop}

%Repeat text
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[1]{
\forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<2}{#1}
}

%Create an environment to repeat text
\NewEnviron{rptenv}{
    \rpt{\BODY}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \begin{rptenv}
}

\AtEndDocument{
    \end{rptenv}
}

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't it work ? If I replace "rptenv" in the hooks by "center", it works like a charm. Is there another way to achieve an automated repetition without changing anything in the body of the file ?

Comment: It won't work. Your environment needs to find the *string* `\end{rptenv}` to stop the parsing. You can't hide it in `\end{document}`. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218589/runaway-argument-error-with-newenviron. I would put the content of the document in some external file and do the loop over `\input{content}`.

Comment: @touhami I forgot to change that to do my minimal example. I made the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work with some tricks:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{forloop}

%Repeat text
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[1]{
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<3}{#1}
}

%Create an environment to repeat text
\NewEnviron{rptenv}{%
    \rpt{\BODY}%
}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\document{%
    \rptenv
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello.
\end{document}
```

`\begin{rptenv}` does not work inside another environment, because the environment name is used to find the `\end{...}` part.

The preamble is not yet finished, when the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is called, therefore the part after the hook of `\begin{document}` must not be called twice. This is fixed in the example by appending `\rptenv` to the command form `\document`.

I have dropped, `\endrptenv`, because it is not needed here (it would expand to `\ignorespacesafterend`, but the job is finished by `\end{document}`, thus spaces afterwards do not matter).